# Visual Studio Test Explorer doesn't show results

Tags: unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio's Test Explorer was not showing the icons that indicate whether tests passed or failed. There were additional problems.

I'd tried rebuilding the solution, reinstalling Visual Studio, as well as rebooting the machine.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted the .vs directory under the solution. The files were corrupt and I could not delete through Windows Explorer. I booted into safe mode command prompt and still could not delete the files. Running chkdsk /f found and fixed a few issues. Now I was able to delete the files in the .vs directory, boot into a normal Windows session and confirm the fix worked.

I hope this helped you fix a similar problem!

Comment: deleting .vs fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Who would have thought the solution would be that easy.  Fixed my issue.

Comment: Rather than just deleting .vs, I tracked down my problem to permissions problems for .vs/[SolutionName]/v16/TestStore/OutputMessages. This is probably due to running the tests as admininistrator at some point in the past. After resetting permissions and giving my user full control, the results showed up in Test Explorer as expected without even restarting VS.

Answer (score 0):

This is really embarrassing but in my case, a Visual Studio window resize had caused the `Error Message` column in the Test Explorer to be expanded to maximum size so all I could see was the little triangles to expand top-level sets of tests and no icons. Resizing the columns fixed it.